# .Click() times out with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with C#. I Got a login webpage with three textboxes and one button. When I'm trying to type in my domain, username and password and press the submit button the page loads but im getting an exception. Please anyone tell me why, I don't get it.

My code looks like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_TextBoxDomain")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_TextBoxUsername")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_TextBoxPassword")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_TextBoxDomain")).SendKeys(".");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_TextBoxUsername")).SendKeys("bla");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_TextBoxPassword")).SendKeys("bla");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginFrame_LoginButton")).Click();
```

edit: WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server of URL

```
http://localhost...
```

timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Are you quite sure that an element with the ID `LoginFrame_LoginButton` does exist?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it exists.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant part of the HTML?

Comment: @Alexander, if the element did not exist then a `NoSuchElementException` would have been raised. According to OP description, however, this is not the case here.

Comment: @Barak, the OP added the Exception after I asked my question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem is **not** within the code that you are executing from client-side (by emulating a client with Selenium).

The problem appears to be within the server that you have running on your local machine, which does not respond to the request that you are sending from the client.

So you can either search for the problem on your server-side code, or post it here for other to examine...